# Two-dimensional collision with two moving objects formula for velocity

Tags: collision-detection

Could anyone explain me this formula?

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/14d5feb68844edae9e31c9cb4a2197ee922e409c

$$\langle \mathbf v_1 - \mathbf v_2, \mathbf x_1 - \mathbf x_2 \rangle =\ ?$$
$$\left\|\mathbf x_1 - \mathbf x_2\right\|^2 =\ ?$$

Comment: It's physics.${}$

Comment: Well, I know that... I want to know about this: <v1 - v2, x1 - x2> = ?, and this: ||x1 - x2||^2 = ?...

Comment: I guess it pops out when you require conservation of energy and momentum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess $\langle a,b\rangle$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, refers to the [scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Regarding $\|a\|^2$, I suppose it is the corresponding norm: $\|a\|^2=\langle a,a\rangle$.

Comment: So <v1 - v2, x1 - x2> = (v1.x - v2.x) * (x1.x - x2.x) + (v1.y - v2.y) * (x1.y - x2.y) + (v1.z - v2.z) * (x1.z - x2.z)?

Comment: @Collision Yes.

Comment: Yes, that's it!